# Increment Value in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive, angular-directive-link

I have a directive which is inside ng-repeat. For example:

```html
<div class="nx-owl-col" nx-owl-carousel-item ng-repeat="slider in slides track by $index">
  <div class="clearfix nx-item-wrapper nx-shaddow1" ng-        if="slider.nativeAdHome==='nativeAdHome'">
    <nx-dfp-ad carousel-data="0"></nx-dfp-ad>

  </div>
</div>
```

My directive:

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module(NgApp)
        .directive('abc', ABC);


    function ABC($compile) {

    return {
      restrict: "EA",
      scope: {
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              scope.count =0;
              element.append("<div id='div-" + scope.count +"' style='height:250px; width:300px;'>");
              $compile(element.contents())(scope)
              scope.count++;
      }
  }
    }


})();
```

There is condition in ng-repeat "slider.nativeAdHome",whenever it will true it will call directive. I want the count should be increment every time directive get called. If it called first time in ng-repeat the count value should be 0, if it called second time count value should be 1 etc.
Please explain how can we achieve this.

Comment: Does it answer you question?

Answer (score 1):

It can be managed by many ways, some of them:

1. two way binding but complex variable like object - `{ count:1 }`
2. service with variable and using it in controller and directive
3. usage of local variable in directive
4. remove isolated scope and increment complex scope variable

**(1)** possible solution - https://jsfiddle.net/maciejsikora/31aqxmy3/ ( open browser console to show results ).

**(4)** possible solution https://jsfiddle.net/maciejsikora/sxn7nkrk/1/ without isolated scope ( open browser console to show results ).

**(3)** I show how manage third propositon, I created local variable count inside directive function. Variable is visible only on directive.

```js
var NgApp=angular.module("app",[]);

(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module("app")
        .controller("cont",Cont)
        .directive('abc', ABC);

    function Cont($scope){
          //example data
          $scope.slides=[
            
             {
               nativeAdHome:"nativeAdHome"
             },{
               nativeAdHome:"somethingElse",
             },
             {
               nativeAdHome:"nativeAdHome"
             },
             {
               nativeAdHome:"nativeAdHome"
             }
          ];
      
    };
  

    function ABC($compile) {

    //local variable - shared between all directive usage
    var count=0;  
      
    return {
      restrict: "EA",
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        
              
        console.log("Current count = "+count);
        count++;
        
      }
     };
      
    }


})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="cont">
  
<div class="nx-owl-col" nx-owl-carousel-item ng-repeat="slider in slides track by $index">
  <div class="clearfix nx-item-wrapper nx-shaddow1" ng-if="slider.nativeAdHome==='nativeAdHome'">
    <abc carousel-data="0"></abc>

  </div>
</div>
  
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the ng-if comparision in controller.

In your main controller

```
   $scope.countNum= 0;
    $scope.IsNativeAdHome = function(slider){
      if(slider.nativeAdHome==='nativeAdHome'){
        $scope.countNum++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

In HTML

```
<div class="nx-owl-col" nx-owl-carousel-item ng-repeat="slider in slides track by $index">
  <div class="clearfix nx-item-wrapper nx-shaddow1" ng-if="IsNativeAdHome(slider)">
    <nx-dfp-ad carousel-data="0" count-num={{countNum}}></nx-dfp-ad>

  </div>
</div>
```

In directive

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module(NgApp)
        .directive('abc', ABC);


    function ABC($compile) {

    return {
      restrict: "EA",
      scope: {
       countNum:'@'
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
              scope.count = scope.countNum;
              element.append("<div id='div-" + scope.count +"' style='height:250px; width:300px;'>");
              $compile(element.contents())(scope)
              scope.count++;
      }
  }
    }


})();
```